# How to resolve this error: TypeError: this.state is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I couldn't resolve this problem, how do I fix this?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Main.css";
import { FaSearch, FaEdit, FaWindowClose } from "react-icons/fa";

export default class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    pesquisaNFE: "",
    resultado: [],
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { resultado } = this.state;
    let { pesquisaNFE } = this.state;
    pesquisaNFE = pesquisaNFE.trim();

    if (resultado.indexOf(pesquisaNFE) !== -1) return;

    const newSearch = [...resultado];

    this.state({
      resultado: [...newSearch, pesquisaNFE],
    });
  };
```

The error:

[image]

Comment: did you at least try to search `how to update state react`  on google ?

Answer (score 5):

To update state you need to call `this.setState`

Change `this.state({` to `this.setState({`